# MakeFile for C++ project

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu

I wrote my own makefile -Which will be used to compile my C++ project-

But I had some issues with it:

1. I need to delete all temporary files; objects, executables and those for UNIX

   I did the first two like this; but how may I implement the latter?

   clean:

   ```
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
   ```
2. I need to zip all files in a `test.zip` folder using tar command in the folder where makefile is -including it-), how may I do that?

   tar:

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 1) Your disregard for punctuation makes your question very difficult to parse. 2) What do you mean "those for UNIX"? Is there a list of them in the makefile already? Can you pick them out of the list of files in the folder? 3) One question per Question, please. 4) Do you mean that you want to zip each file, or make a tarball of all of the files, and then zip that?

Comment: @Beta Hi, I was requested to delete all OBJS and EXEC (As I already did) plus all other temporary files. Regarding zip In the current location of the make file there are only files (no folders) I want to zip them all together including the make file of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to delete all "temporary files", but a temporary file is a file that people don't intend to keep very long. There is no way for a tool like Make to know people's intentions without being told.

To create a zipped archive of `Makefile` and `test.zip/` from the command line, you can use a command like:

```
tar -czvf archive.tgz Makefile test.zip
```

You can put that in a rule in the makefile like this:

```
archive.tgz:
    tar -czvf archive.tgz Makefile test.zip
```

Further refinements are possible, once you have this much working correctly.

Comment: Hi, you got me wrong, I want to make a zip file using make command, In other words I want to type make tar and then see the zip file being created

Comment: @john: Yeah, that's what the *rule* is for. You didn't specify that you wanted the target of the rule to be "tar," so I chose "archive.tgz".

Comment: Thanks you so much, may you kindly let me chat with you to take a short lock at my file (only 10 lines) I would really appreciate this. Again Thanks!

Comment: @john: I don't know how to open a chat room, but you can edit your question to append the makefile.